# removing a class when a search box is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

**TLDR;** The functionality I'm trying to create in this code example is upon clicking a box (collapsible has `active` class), and then you click on the **search box**, the active class is removed closing the collapsible. Currently, the remove class is not working. Any idea why?

In more detail:

I have a list of collapsible blocks get an `active` class when they are clicked. You can search a search box to filter out which block you want to be displayed, and thus click on it to display more content. I have realized that when you go back to search and didn't 'unclick' a box (to close the collapsible) the box is still `active` (which makes perfect sense).

I had an idea that upon search box focus, I would loop through all the collapsible and remove the active class itself (in turn, closing the collapsible).

I've gotten to the point where I can find which collapsible is active, but I cannot remove the `active` class.

Is this because the box was initially clicked to add the class and has to be physically clicked once again to remove it?

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

function searchClick() {
  var searchTable;
  searchTable = document.getElementById("search-table");
  faqButtons = searchTable.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for (i = 0; i < faqButtons.length; i++) {
    if (faqButtons[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      console.log('THIS ONE: ', faqButtons[i]);
      faqButtons[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.collapsible span {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}



.collapsible .active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.content p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-faq">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="search-faq" placeholder="Search for FAQ" onfocus="searchClick()" />
</div>

<div id="search-table" class="superHidden">
  <div id="wolfandgrizzly-FAQ-search">
    <h1>A to B sales</h1>
    <button class="collapsible"><span>What are our shipping policies?</span></button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        They are crazy cool.
      </p>
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible"><span>Are you making more products?</span></button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        We'll sell you more very soon
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So you need functionality to whenever someone click on input field you `.active` class will be removed ?

Comment: The `.active` class is being removed fine. Your problem is that you're using JS to set the height of the item instead of the `.active` class, so the removal of the class doesn't do anything visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you are getting that the `active` class is not being removed. It doesn't appear that there is a problem with that. I think the problem is that you are showing the answers via `maxHeight` setting, but you aren't resetting it when you click the search box. I've updated it in this snippet, but essentially it boiled down to adding the following in your loop:

```
var content = faqButtons[i].nextElementSibling
content.style.maxHeight = null
```

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

function searchClick() {
  var searchTable;
  searchTable = document.getElementById("search-table");
  faqButtons = searchTable.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for (i = 0; i < faqButtons.length; i++) {
    if (faqButtons[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      console.log('THIS ONE: ', faqButtons[i]);
      faqButtons[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    var content = faqButtons[i].nextElementSibling
    content.style.maxHeight = null
  }
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.collapsible span {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}



.collapsible .active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.content p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-faq">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="search-faq" placeholder="Search for FAQ" onfocus="searchClick()" />
</div>

<div id="search-table" class="superHidden">
  <div id="wolfandgrizzly-FAQ-search">
    <h1>A to B sales</h1>
    <button class="collapsible"><span>What are our shipping policies?</span></button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        They are crazy cool.
      </p>
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible"><span>Are you making more products?</span></button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        We'll sell you more very soon
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Unless there's a really good reason for it to be done using JS, I'd say switch to using CSS to show and hide the elements.

Comment: @NathanArthur I thought the same thing, but the OP was using the scrollHeight to use in the maxHeight value, so I figured I would leave it that way. That is a fairly reasonable use case for JavaScript.

Comment: @NathanArthur do you mind showing me an example of this in CSS, I couldn't think of a way of doing this other then in JS.

Comment: @RobertOchinski Sure, I'm on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses as little JavaScript as possible. If JavaScript is disabled, the only thing that will break is the search box. Sections will still open and close as expected when clicked.

The accordion stores its state in checkboxes, one in each section. Each section's title is a `label` element which toggles that section's checkbox when clicked. The sections are expanded and collapsed using CSS `:checked` selectors.

```js
var sections = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".accordion li")),
  searchAccordion = function() {
    var value = document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase();
    sections.map(function(section) {
      var content = section.textContent.toLowerCase();
      section.querySelector("input").checked = content.includes(value);
    });
  };
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.accordion {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: -1rem;
}

.accordion li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.accordion input {
  display: none;
}

.accordion label {
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: background-color 100ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.accordion label:hover {
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}

.accordion .content {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.accordion input:checked ~ .content { 
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<input id="search" onKeyup="searchAccordion()" type="text" placeholder="Search for FAQ" autocomplete="off">

<h1>A to B sales</h1>

<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="section1">
    <label for="section1">What are our shipping policies?</label>
    <div class="content">They are crazy cool.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="section2">
    <label for="section2">Are you making more products?</label>
    <div class="content">We'll sell you more very soon</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that's a neat way of doing, I defiantly see the benefits of that! I appreciate the extra effort showing me, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. :D